# Examples of independent $\Sigma_4^1$ statements

Tags: forcing, descriptive-set-theory, independence-results

As in the title, I'm looking for examples of $\Sigma^1_4$ (preferably complete) sentences which are independent from ZFC in both ways, namely given a model $V$ we can extend it to $V'$ where such a sentence holds, but also extend it to a model $V''$ where such sentence fails.

By Shoenfield Theorem $\Sigma_4^1$ (or $\Pi^1_4$) is the lowest available complexity of such a formula, and that's why I'm looking for such examples.

Comment: What you mean is that the sentence is neither upward nor downward absolute.

Comment: You can't achieve what you want: large cardinals imply projective absoluteness, so in their presence you cannot change the truth value of projective statements.

Comment: (Unless by "extend" you do not mean "by set forcing".)

Comment: Ok, but isn't it the case that I can firstly collapse large cardinals and then procede as before? I don't know much about them, but I don't see obstacles for doing that.

Comment: Not if there are a proper class of them

Comment: In some sense the answer below is best possible. The negation can be forced (with set forcing) over any model of ZFC, while its truth can be forced using class forcing. In General, class forcing cannot be replaced by set forcing (for any given $\Sigma^1_4$ sentence) by Andrés Caicedos comment

Comment: Thanks for clearifying! I'm not so advanced into large cardinals, this was usefull. However, I still have a feeling that in a book to Set Theory, right after introducing the Shoenfield Theorem, and its consequences for $\Sigma^1_3$ and $\Pi^1_3$ formulas, there should be a remark like "Thesis of Shoenfield Theorem does not holds for higher classes, since e.g. the following sentences are independent of ZFC". So I still hope some new examples will appear.

Answer (score 7):

As a starting point, think about the sentence "There is a nonconstructible real." This is $\Sigma^1_3$ and clearly not downwards-absolute. However, it is upwards-absolute.

To get the desired situation, we "relativize" and consider the sentence

> There is some real $r$ such that every real $s$ is constructible *relative to $r$*.

*(That is, for some $r\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}\cap L[r]$.)*

This is $\Sigma^1_4$, and is neither downwards nor upwards absolute.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! But I will wait with closing this question, maybe some other examples will appear.